# Embedded a specific tweet in a R Shiny app

Tags: r, twitter, shiny

I'm totally newbie in Web and all that stuff.
I want to be able to **display a specific tweet** from a user input in a Shiny app.
Here is my try from this post : [How can i embed a twitter timeline in a shiny app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257922/how-can-i-embed-a-twitter-timeline-in-a-shiny-app) . I'm trying to display this tweet : https://twitter.com/AndrewYNg/status/894994683931148288

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head("<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)    [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');</script>"),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel()
    , mainPanel(
      a("Tweets by Andrew Ng", class="twitter-tweet"
        , href = "https://twitter.com/AndrewYNg/status/894994683931148288"
      )
    )
  )
)
, server = function(input, output, session){

}
)
)
```

It does not display the tweet but the link to the tweet. I guess the tag$head does not contain the good thing but I cannot figure out what it is supposed to be.

Comment: Tweets are embedded differently from timelines. Check that the markup is correct - https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrap the script in a `shiny::HTML()` so the content doesn't get HTML escaped. `<script>` is getting escaped to `&lt;script&gt;` in your example. Or better, use `shiny::tags$script()`
2. Check the Twitter docs to see how to embed a Tweet and make sure the markup is correct: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$script("!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)    [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,'script','twitter-wjs');")
    ),
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),
      mainPanel(
        HTML('
        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">
          Want to break into AI? You can learn Deep Learning from new deeplearning.ai courses on Coursera:
          <a href="https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning">https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning</a></p>&mdash; Andrew Ng (@AndrewYNg)
          <a href="https://twitter.com/AndrewYNg/status/894994683931148288?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">August 8, 2017</a>
        </blockquote>
      ')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
))
```

I used raw HTML for the tweet, but you could convert it to HTML tag objects.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. You should receive the bounty in 13 hours. Tell me if it s not the case. I do not know how this bounty stuff work!

Comment: why the "date" and the "number of people are talking about tweet" on the embedded tweet different than open the URL on the browser?